# undefined variable in url with get parameter in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

First off, I fully intend to `AJAXify` my entire page, though I am first building each page as its own just for clarity's sake and to avoid some of the up front hassle involved in AJAX.

All was well until I received this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: q
Filename: controllers/welcome.php
Line Number: 93
```

Here is my Welcome code:

```
    function find($cliqid = '')
    {
        $search = $this->input->get($q);
        $q      = $search['q'];
        if ($cliqid == '') { $cliq  = "Find a new Cliq to Join!"; } else { 
        $cliq                           = $this->logic_m->get_cliq($cliqid);
            }
        $data['page']                   = "Create a new cliq under the ".$cliq. " Cliq!";

        //build components
        $page['head']                   = $this->load->view('template/components/head', $data, TRUE);
        $page['header']                 = $this->components_m->header($cliqid);
        $page['cliqbar']                = $this->components_m->cliqbar($cliqid);
        $page['content']                = $q;
        $page['slideout']               = $this->components_m->slideout();

        $this->load->view('template/template' ,$page);
    }
```

and here is the URL thats opening the page `/welcome/find/6/?q=234`

`$page['content']` is actually displaying variable `$q` correctly, so I am not sure why its throwing out an error, or how to get rid of it.

Thank you!

Comment: you need to set $q before `$search = $this->input->get($q);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an issue with this line:

```
$search = $this->input->get($q);
```

It should be:

```
$q = $this->input->get('q');
```

`$q` isn't defined yet!

EDIT: You'll also want to take out the line below where $q is redefined.

Comment: ahh...thank you!  my old eyes glossed over that 20 times...ill add correct in 9 mins (and edit this out)